# Delete a specific folder if it is empty, from batch file in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

I want to delete a folder called "NEW" but only if that folder is empty.

Here's what I tried:

```
if exist "NEW\*" goto finished
if not exist "NEW\*" goto remove_new

:remove_new
rd /s /q "NEW\"
goto finished

:finished
exit
```

The above seems to be taking into account that the NEW folder exists so it's not deleting it?

Comment: This is a classic X-Y problem. You had a problem, didn't know the best answer, came up with one yourself and you now need help for this. rd natively supports this, so no need to do fancy programming. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, rd will only remove folders that are not empty. A folder can be considered non-empty too if it has subfolders.

By implying /s, you say: remove all files and folders inside the folder and then delete this folder.

If you simply do:

```
rd /q new
```

It will attempt to remove folder new. If it finds files and/or folders, it will will display the message `The folder is not empty.`

The /q will not remove that message. In order to silently attempt to remove the folder but not display the error, use the following command:

```
rd /q new 2>nul
```

This command says: try to silently delete the folder. Any errors displayed on screen should be piped out of existence (aka, not shown).

Comment: Cheers LPChip I vaguely remember now you've said, but I remember rd not removing folders if they were empty (the opposite) without using a switch. I didn't know it has this built in.

Comment: :) You're welcome. :)

Comment: @LPChip funny you answered exactly at the same time...  a small correction though: you don't need the `/q` switch if you don't use the `/s` switch.

Comment: @Albin indeed, but if the folder does exists, then it will show a message deleting the folder, which will be suppressed by /q. I kept using /q because it is in the original code. I'm fairly certain they don't want to see it being deleted either, otherwise the /q would not have been in the question either.

Comment: @LPChip No, it won't ask for confirmation with empty folders (or least not on the current/past versions of CMD or power shell). `/q` is only required if you use the `/s` switch (for non-empty folders). Just try it yourself, you'll see ;)

PS. if you leave the `/q` it won't "hurt" but it's just unnecessary clutter with no functionality (but might be a problem if the switch is introduced with a different function in the future)

Comment: @Albin I'm not talking about the confirmation. I'm talking about displaying that it removed a folder if it succeeds.

Comment: @LPChip no, you are not correct, it doesn't make a difference, the `/q` is just superfluous. As I said, just try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you only delete empty folders, instead of the whole script you can simply use `rd` without the `/s` switch (and the `q`). So your command will be:

```
rd "NEW\"
```

This will only delete the directory if it exists AND if its empty. Otherwise it will return an error message.

PS. Folder names are not case sensitive just `rd "new\"` will do.

PPS. Although you don't need it necessary in this case, the `""` is a good idea in case you use folders with spaces like `"new 01"`.

PPPS. You don't need the backslash (`\`) at the end of the folder name either, since `rd` only applies to folders. But it helps to differentiate between a files and a folder with other commands. E.g. `exist "foldername\"` will apply on folders `exist "name"` will apply to files and/or folders.

Comment: Who are you trying to fool here? Post edit history tells a different story: answered 32 mins ago, 
edited 26 mins ago, |My reply, 24 mins ago|,
Post Deleted by Albin, occurred 24 mins ago,
edited 21 mins ago,
Post Undeleted by Albin, occurred 21 mins ago, 
edited 2 mins ago.

Comment: @LPChip what do you mean that I'm trying to fool s.o.? I just wanted to let you know, that I edited my answer so your comment is obsolete - you wrote a comment to my answer's first version with the "fancy programming", didn't you?

Comment: I removed my comment, but I'm very puzzled by your answer, as it is basically identical to mine now, except less explainatory. You first had a completely different answer, you deleted it like 8 minutes after posting, then edited it and undeleted it to an answer that is saying the same thing as mine. What is the point of your answer then?

Comment: I don't know who did the -1. Wasn't me. But was possibly due to recovering a deleted answer with another answer that did not add anything.

Comment: @LPChip That could very well be. I deleted my answer after I realized I misunderstood the question, so nobody will read it while I can edit it in peace. I could have deleted my answer after I read yours but I've already done all the editing anyway, and since my answer uses the switches in a correct way (you don't need `/q` without the `/s`) and is still a little different to yours...  so I just left it be. Maybe it helps a user...

Comment: I know LPChip answered first, it's run into hours by now but yesterday, his reply said it was answered 20 minutes ago while the next one said 19 minutes. Those were the first two replies and it was definitely LPChip first, by 1 minute!

Comment: @bat_cmd fyi, you don't have to use the "minutes/hours/days ago"-time. If you click on the little clock symbol under the vote up/down and do a mouse over over the time there, you'll get the exact time stamps. PS. it's not important who was first, you can give the accept to whatever answer you want. So no need to explain yourself. I have loads of unaccepted answers...

Comment: @Albin and if you check the edit history, you see a completely different story, where it confirms what bat_cmd is saying.

Comment: @LPChip I never doubted that you did hit the answer button one minute before I did (19 seconds to be exact)...  and I explained why I deleted&changed&undeleted my answer and left it be despite being similar to yours (only because you asked)... not sure if is there a point to this discussion? If you know, please enlighten me (seriously)...

Comment: To me its not a discussion. I'm only very puzzled why you chosen to first delete the answer that totally missed the mark, and then 8 minutes later than my answer, undeleted it with basically the same answer as mine.

Comment: @LPChip sure thing, did you see my comment with the time stamp `Sep 5 at 10:02`?? That's where I explained, why I deleted and why I left it be even after I realized it's similar to yours.

Comment: I did see it, just following the continuation of the conversation and explaining that the first post was not 1 minute difference, but the first time the answer is in its current state is actually quite a lot later. At the time you deleted your answer, mine was up and I commented on your answer. So even before you edited your answer, you should have seen my answer already which made it seem like you are looking for excuses to keep your answer up and which is also likely why someone felt it necessary to downvote you.

Comment: @LPChip ok, I see, so, you are upset that in your eyes I "copied" your answer. Honestly, I didn't but it's a mute point since I wouldn't be able to prove it anyway, and I like to keep my answer since I added quite a bit of information by now. But no worries, just let me know if it would suffice if I add an `expanding LPChips answer`? Or `Note: LPChip answered a few minutes before me`? (This question is so basic, I don't really care, it's more important to keep everyone happy for the community's sake...  what you think would be appropriate to make it look better)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113295/discussion-between-albin-and-lpchip).

Answer (score 0):

Your command **`rd /q new`** or **`rd new`** works perfectly for delete a **empty** folder **only**.

For folders containing files and/or subfolders, this command **does not work**.

**Obs.: 1** To delete a folder containing subfolder/recursively, add `/s`:

---

**1.** Folder **exists** and is **empty**:

```bat
rd /q new   ⁄⁄ it work

rem :: or... 
rd new     ⁄⁄ it work
```

**2.** Folder **contains** file or subfolders (**empty** or not):

```bat
rd /q new   ⁄⁄ does not work

rem :: or... 
rd new      ⁄⁄ does not work
```

**3.** Folder **contains** file or subfolders (**empty** or not):

```bat
rd /q /s new   ⁄⁄ it work

rem :: or... 
rd /s new     ⁄⁄ it work
```

**4.** You do not need to use **`:label`** to handle the redirect actions when your **`if exist`** returns **true/false**, you can have these actions in a single line, or single block, with more accurate message display too:

- One line:

```bat
2>nul rmdir /q /s new\. && echo\Folder Removed || if exist "New\." (Echo\Folder not Removed)else Echo\Folder not exist
```

- In one block:

```bat
@echo off 

2>nul rd /q /s new\. && ( 
     echo\Folder Removed 
)||( 
     if exist "New\." (
          echo\Folder not Removed
        ) else echo\Folder new not Exist 
    )
```

---

- All possibles **outputs/cases**:

```bat
Folder Exist and was Removed: echo\Folder Removed

Folder Exist and was not Removed: echo\Folder not Removed 

Folder not Exist and was Not Removed: echo\Folder not Exist
```

---

**Obs.: 2** Test the existence of a folder and avoid confusing it with a file of the same name (and without an extension) using "folder."

---

```bat
2>nul ⇆ omit error/redirect
  rmdir /q new ⇆  remove folder command
    && ⇆ operator take action for retun 0 == do  echo\Folder Removed
      || ⇆ operator take action for retun 0 retun non 0 == do ( ... 
        if True Exist new ⇆ (
             Folder Exists and has not been Removed⇆ if condition True 
            ) else/False Folder does not exist and because of that it was not removed ⇆ if condition False
```

---

**For your specific case you can use:**

- In one line:

```bat
2>nul rd /q new\. && echo\Folder New Empty Removed || if exist "New\." (echo\Folder not Empty and Not Removed) else echo\Folder not Exist
```

---

- In one block:

```bat
@echo off 

2>nul rd /q new\. && ( 
     echo\Folder New Empty Removed 
)||( 
     if exist "New\." (
          echo\Folder not Empty and Not Removed
        ) else echo\Folder not Exist 
    )
```

- All possibles **outputs/cases**:

```bat
Folder New Empty Exist and was Removed: echo\Folder Empty Removed

Folder New Exist and is not Empty and was Not Removed: echo\Folder not Empty and Not Removed 

Folder New not Exist and was Not Removed: echo\Folder not Exist
```

---

To delete a folder and only if it is empty and does not have empty subfolders

```bat
@echo off 

2>nul dir /b "new\."|findstr . >nul && (
     echo\Folder New non Empty and not was Removed
)||( 
     2>nul rd /q "new\." && (
         echo\Folder new Empty Removed 
    )||(
         echo\Folder new Not Exist
       )
    )
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√]  **[RMDir | RD](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)**

  [√]  **[If else condition..](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√]  **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√]  **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**